# Can I use the entrance to Arlanda North in terminal 5 to get to Arlanda Central station?

Tags: airport-transfer, train-stations, arn, sj

I'm travelling by an intercity train run by SJ from Arlanda C (i.e. Arlanda Central station), and as such I'll have to find my way to the train station there. Looking at Arlanda's page about taking the train[1](https://www.swedavia.com/arlanda/train/), long-distance trains arrive and depart from "Arlanda Central station in SkyCity". This, to me, would imply that this is a different station from Arlanda South and Arlanda North mentioned on the same page. However, looking at the map over SkyCity[2](https://www.swedavia.com/arlanda/finding-your-way-at-the-airport/), it looks like the entrances to Arlanda Central station and Arlanda North are located in the same place. However, looking at the map over terminal 5, only the express train station (i.e., Arlanda North) is mentioned.

With this in mind I would like to know, are these stations located in the same place? And, can I just walk to the entrance to Arlanda North in terminal 5 to get to the intercity trains, or do I have to first head to SkyCity and use that entrance?

Comment: I think the intercity trains only serve Arlanda C. At least that is what Wikipedia thinks.

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe the SkyCity map you are linking to is incorrect. Although the entrances to Arlanda C (in SkyCity) and Arlanda North (in terminal 5) are only about 200m apart (2-3 minute walk), I don't think you can get to the Arlanda North platform using the entrance in SkyCity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arlanda North and South stations are only used by the Arlanda Express trains, so you will not be able to access Intercity services from there. Sky City is sort of a hub in the middle of the airport complex for hotels, offices, services and transport links: that's where you'll find the entrance to Arlanda Central station. It's a short walk from Terminal 5, and you won't need to brave the Swedish weather as it's all through interior walkways.